# Pandas dataframe groupby plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn

I have a dataframe which is structured as:

```
          Date   ticker  adj_close 
0   2016-11-21     AAPL    111.730     
1   2016-11-22     AAPL    111.800    
2   2016-11-23     AAPL    111.230    
3   2016-11-25     AAPL    111.790     
4   2016-11-28     AAPL    111.570    
...          
8   2016-11-21      ACN    119.680            
9   2016-11-22      ACN    119.480              
10  2016-11-23      ACN    119.820              
11  2016-11-25      ACN    120.740 
...
```

How can I plot based on the ticker the `adj_close` versus `Date`?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

### Simple plot,

you can use:

```
df.plot(x='Date',y='adj_close')
```

Or you can set the index to be `Date` beforehand, then it's easy to plot the column you want:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df['adj_close'].plot()
```

---

### If you want a chart with one series by `ticker` on it

You need to [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) before:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.groupby('ticker')['adj_close'].plot(legend=True)
```

[image]

---

### If you want a chart with individual subplots:

```
grouped = df.groupby('ticker')

ncols=2
nrows = int(np.ceil(grouped.ngroups/ncols))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(12,4), sharey=True)

for (key, ax) in zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axes.flatten()):
    grouped.get_group(key).plot(ax=ax)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 36):

Similar to Julien's answer above, I had success with the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
for key, grp in df.groupby(['ticker']):
    ax.plot(grp['Date'], grp['adj_close'], label=key)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

This solution might be more relevant if you want more control in matlab.

> *Solution inspired by: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/52526454/10521959](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52526454/10521959_)*

Answer (score 9):

- The question is ***How can I plot based on the ticker the adj_close versus Date?***

  - This can be accomplished by reshaping the dataframe to a wide format with `.pivot` or `.groupby`, or by plotting the existing long form dataframe directly with `seaborn`.
- In the following sample data, the `'Date'` column has a `datetime64[ns] Dtype`.

  - Convert the `Dtype` with `pandas.to_datetime` if needed.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### Imports and Sample Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web  # for sample data; this can be installed with conda if using Anaconda, otherwise pip
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample stock data, where .iloc[:, [5, 6]] selects only the 'Adj Close' and 'tkr' column
tickers = ['aapl', 'acn']
df = pd.concat((web.DataReader(ticker, data_source='yahoo', start='2020-01-01', end='2022-06-21')
                .assign(ticker=ticker) for ticker in tickers)).iloc[:, [5, 6]]

# display(df.head())
        Date  Adj Close ticker
0 2020-01-02  73.785904   aapl
1 2020-01-03  73.068573   aapl
2 2020-01-06  73.650795   aapl
3 2020-01-07  73.304420   aapl
4 2020-01-08  74.483604   aapl

# display(df.tail())
           Date   Adj Close ticker
1239 2022-06-14  275.119995    acn
1240 2022-06-15  281.190002    acn
1241 2022-06-16  270.899994    acn
1242 2022-06-17  275.380005    acn
1243 2022-06-21  282.730011    acn
```

### [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) & [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

- `pandas` plots with `matplotlib` as the default backend.
- Reshaping the dataframe with `pandas.DataFrame.pivot` converts from long to wide form, and puts the dataframe into the correct format to plot.
- `.pivot` does not aggregate data, so if there is more than 1 observation per index, per ticker, then use [`.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)
- Adding `subplots=True` will produce a figure with two subplots.

```py
# reshape the long form data into a wide form
dfp = df.pivot(index='Date', columns='ticker', values='Adj Close')

# display(dfp.head())
ticker           aapl         acn
Date                             
2020-01-02  73.785904  203.171112
2020-01-03  73.068573  202.832764
2020-01-06  73.650795  201.508224
2020-01-07  73.304420  197.157654
2020-01-08  74.483604  197.544434

# plot
ax = dfp.plot(figsize=(11, 6))
```

[image]

---

- Use `seaborn`, which accepts long form data, so reshaping the dataframe to a wide form isn't necessary.
- [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) is a high-level api for `matplotlib`

### [`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html): axes-level plot

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 6))
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Date', y='Adj Close', hue='ticker', ax=ax)
```

### [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html): figure-level plot

- Adding `row='ticker'`, or `col='ticker'`, will generate a figure with two subplots.

```py
g = sns.relplot(kind='line', data=df, x='Date', y='Adj Close', hue='ticker', aspect=1.75)
```

[image]