# Plot data in long format by group in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
test = pd.DataFrame({"series":["plot1","plot1","plot1","plot2","plot2","plot2"],
                     "ind_var": [0,1,2,0,1,2],
                     "dep_var": [0,1,2,0,2,4]})
```

`plot1` is described by `f(x)=x`, while `plot2` is `g(x)=2x`.

I want to plot both series in the same figure and have them share the same x and y axis. I came across [this solution](https://python-graph-gallery.com/122-multiple-lines-chart/), but it requires the data to be in *wide* format (it needs one line of code per group, which I find inconvenient).

I want to know if there's something similar to the `color` argument from `ggplot2`. That is, an argument which will plot one column grouped by `test["series"]`. The advantage of doing this is more evident when there's multiple series, so you don't have to write one line per series.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494942/pandas-dataframe-groupby-plot) and this is as close as I could get:

```py
# test.set_index("ind_var", inplace=True) This is the line I was missing
test.groupby("series")["dep_var"].plot(legend=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Almost]

Is there a way to plot both series in a single figure using something along the lines of `grooupby`?

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you found?

Comment: If I were to follow the first one I would have to write 135 lines of code (I have 135 groups). The second solution didn't work. Both series share the same `x` variable, so they should cover the same range and be plotted over the same y scale.

Comment: Loops are one option. At the same time, doesn't pandas handle this situation out of the box?

Comment: No, that is not true. `"plot1"` contains x values 0,1,2, while `"plot2"` contains 3,4,5.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not that I know of. Please explain.

Comment: `sns.lineplot(x='ind_var', y='dep_var', hue='series', data=test)`?

Comment: Or `test.pivot(index='ind_var', columns='series', values='dep_var').plot()`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest My bad! I edited the question.

Comment: Yeah, but you didn't edit the image. With the changed data you will get exactly what you ask for.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You are absolutely right. I updated the question accordingly. Thanks! Regardless, I was looking for something along the lines of Quang Hong's first comment.

Comment: @QuangHoang Your first comment is exactly what I was looking for. Even the syntax looks like `ggplot2`.  You want to go ahead and post the answer so I can close the question?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Is there any chance you could remove the duplicate suggestion? I was specifically looking for an answer using `matplotlib`, not `seaborn`. It just so happens that I liked the `seaborn` solution, but I wasn't asking for it explicitly. If anything, shouldn't this be a duplicate of the question I made a reference to originally?