# Cooccurence table of values of two columns with non-overlapping set of entries

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

---

### Reproducible setup

I have a dataframe:

```
df=\
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A':['a','b','b','c','d','d','c','b'],
                        'B':['p','q','p','q','r','r','p','q']})
```

ie

```
   A  B
0  a  p
1  b  q
2  b  p
3  c  q
4  d  r
5  d  r
6  c  p
7  b  q
```

If a value appears in column `B`, it surely does not appear in column `A` and vice-versa. The post [Cooccurence matrix from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63598670/cooccurence-matrix-from-pandas-dataframe) discusses a similar setup, but there are important differences: the form of both input and output there is different (though similar information content). It also does not require the columns to have distinct set of entries, unlike my current post.

---

## Aim

I want to create a new dataframe, which shows how many times each entry from `A` appeared together with each entry from `A`. I would like the column of this new dataframe to be entries from `df`'s column `A`, so the result would look like this:

```
res=\
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'B':['p','q','r'],
                        'a':[1,0,0],
                        'b':[1,2,0],
                        'c':[1,1,0],
                        'd':[0,0,2]})
```

ie:

```
   B  a  b  c  d
0  p  1  1  1  0
1  q  0  2  1  0
2  r  0  0  0  2
```

---

## Question

How can I transform `df` to the dataframe described above?

---

### What I've tried

**A)**

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38933130/8565438) to the question [Group by two columns and count the occurrences of each combination in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933071/group-by-two-columns-and-count-the-occurrences-of-each-combination-in-pandas), I came up with:

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).size().to_frame(name = 'size').reset_index()
```

ie

```
   A  B  size
0  a  p     1
1  b  p     1
2  b  q     2
3  c  p     1
4  c  q     1
5  d  r     2
```

Which is similar, but in a different form. Probably could transform it to my form but probably a more efficient method exists.

---

**B)**

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65458310/8565438), tried:

```
df.pivot_table('A', aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
```

But this gives `ValueError: No group keys passed!`. I am unsure whether the linked post is worked where it was posted, so I abandoned this path.

---

**C)**

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63598866/8565438) to the question [Cooccurence matrix from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63598670/cooccurence-matrix-from-pandas-dataframe), I came up with this:

```
s=df.stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).ne(0).astype(int)
s=s.T.dot(s).astype(float)
np.fill_diagonal(s.values, np.nan)
s=s[['a','b','c','d']].drop(index=['a','b','c','d'])
s.index.name = 'B'
s=s.astype(int)
s.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

ie

```
   B  a  b  c  d
0  p  1  1  1  0
1  q  0  2  1  0
2  r  0  0  0  2
```

Which is what I want. It is rather convoluted and long solution however. I would prefer a more compact one.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['B'], df['A'])`?

Comment: For B) use `df.pivot_table(index='B', columns='A', aggfunc='size').fillna(0)`

Comment: For A) use `df.groupby(['B', 'A']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)`

Comment: For C) you over-complicated things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        "A": ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "c", "b"],
        "B": ["p", "q", "p", "q", "r", "r", "p", "q"],
    }
)

res = pd.crosstab(df['B'], df['A'])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
A  a  b  c  d
B            
p  1  1  1  0
q  0  2  1  0
r  0  0  0  2
```