# Plotting in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Very new to coding, so please excuse the lack of finesse. I will try to describe my problem as best as I can.

I have a tabular list of 'City_names' and 'Year_spending', and would like to create plots of spending versus time (Year), color coded by city_names. How would I best approach this in Pandas?

This is the current format of my table:

| City_names | Year_2000_spending | Year_2002_spending | Year_2003_spending |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City 1 | $1 | $5 | $1 |
| City 2 | $8 | $7 | $7 |
| City 3 | $5 | $3 | $9 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas dataframe groupby plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494942/pandas-dataframe-groupby-plot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with this. This gives a bar graph of **spending versus time (Year), color coded by city_names**, as shown below.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['City 1', '$1', '$5', '$1'],['City 2', '$8', '$7', '$7'],['City 3', '$5', '$3', '$9']], columns=['City_names', 'Year_2000_spending', 'Year_2002_spending', 'Year_2003_spending'])
df=df.replace('\$','',regex=True)
df[['Year_2000_spending', 'Year_2002_spending', 'Year_2003_spending']] = df[['Year_2000_spending', 'Year_2002_spending', 'Year_2003_spending']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
df = df.set_index('City_names')
df = df.T.reset_index()

df.plot.bar(x='index')
plt.xticks(rotation=0, ha='right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I tried this to the letter, but keep getting this error message "no numeric data to plot" even though line 3 of the code converts to numeric. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: If you update the question with your data and code, It would help us in trying to resolve your issue.

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue. Somehow, the executing the following code kept converting the dtype back to 'object': df = df.T.reset_index(). I was able to re-convert to numeric and plot the graph. Thanks again for your guidance!