# Plot multiple bar plots by groupby

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot bar chart when the field force visited the clients. I have defined some time intervals and in the occurrences column, it refers to the number of time a client was visited during this time interval.

Now, what I would like to have, is 6 bar chart that represent the distribution per day (Monday to Saturday, thus 6) per client. Something like below:

[image: Example of the wished output]

The problem is, I have more than 375 clients and I would like to have a file output for each client with the graphs above.

This how my dataframe looks like:

| Interval | Client | Occurrences | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08:00:00 - 08:15:00 | A | 1 | Monday |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 19:45:00 - 20:00:00 | A | 10 | Monday |
| 08:00:00 - 08:15:00 | A | 2 | Tuesday |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 08:00:00 - 08:15:00 | B | 4 | Monday |

And this is the code that gives me the output I would like to plot:

`result.groupby(['Client','Day','Interval'])['Occurrences'].sum()`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to create a plot for data, remember your x axis should be same for all data. For example, you have to have same number of data for each one. Records length should not be changed in one plot. Did you made any sample codes?

Comment: Yes, I do have the same number of rows per client and per day. I used this code for creating the graph: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494942/pandas-dataframe-groupby-plot

Answer (score 0):

I have created and coded something similar to the sample data presented. The outermost loop is processed by client and the inner rule process is processed by day of the week. However, the grouping results do not necessarily have the same interval name, so we join them with a common interval name and update the missing values as 0. At the end of the loop, the graph is saved by client name. I think a horizontal graph, rather than a vertical bar graph, would be more effective for visualization if the subplots are in chronological order, with interval values on the y-axis and counts on the x-axis. If you need a horizontal bar graph, please modify it yourself.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2021-01-01 08:00:00', '2021-04-30 20:00:00', freq='15min'),
                  'Client': random.choices(list('ABCDEFGHIJK'), k=11473),
                   'Occurrences': np.random.randint(0,10,11473)})

df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df = df.between_time('08:00:00', '19:45:00')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

weekdays = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
df['day'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:weekdays[x.weekday()])

df['Interval'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')[-8:]+'-'+(x+datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')[-8:])

idx_df = pd.DataFrame(df['Interval'].unique())
for c in df['Client'].unique():
    dff = df.query('Client == @c')
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,6, figsize=(20,15), sharey=True)
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05)
    for wd, ax in zip(weekdays, axs.flatten()):
        dfs = dff.query('day == @wd').groupby(['Interval'])['Occurrences'].sum().to_frame('cnt')
        idx_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df['Interval'].unique())
        dfm = idx_df.merge(dfs, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer').fillna(0)
        ax.barh(np.arange(0,48,1), dfm['cnt'], height=0.9)
        ax.invert_yaxis() 
        ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,48,1))
        ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,35,5))
        ax.set_ylim(-0.5,47.5)
        ax.set_title(wd)
        fig.savefig(c+'.png')
```

[image]